# Clear two TextBoxes and checkBox using JavaScript on TextChanged or CheckedChanged events

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

clear the other two controls if third controls value changes -- using Javascript

I have two textBoxes and a checkBox

txtExpiryDate--with ajaxCalenderExtender

txtDaysToExpire

chkExpired --checkbox

The issue that I cannot fix is, if the value in  **any** of the above three controls is changed (on client side) the **other two** should be cleared..

Like if a date is selected in `txtExpiryDate`, values of other two controls should be cleared to: `txtDaysToExpire.Text="";` and `chkExpired.Checked = false` .. and similarly if `chkExpired.Checked = true`, then **other two should be cleared**.. Hope it makes it clear to understand.. Please have a look at the mark-up

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlExpiry" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtExpiryDate" EventName="TextChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtDaysToExpire" EventName="TextChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkExpired" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="leftaligntxt">
                <tr>
                    <td width="44%" align="left">
                        Expiry Date
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="txtExpiryDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calExtExpiryDate" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            PopupButtonID="imgBtnCal" TargetControlID="txtExpiryDate">
                        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnCal" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/FQBlue/img/Calendar_img.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="44%">
                        Days to Expire
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDaysToExpire" runat="server" Width="80px" OnTextChanged="txtDaysToExpire_TextChanged"
                            ></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="txtDaysToExpire_NumericUpDownExtender" runat="server"
                            Maximum="15000" Minimum="0" TargetControlID="txtDaysToExpire" Width="100">
                        </ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkExpired" runat="server" Text="Show Expired" AutoPostBack="True"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkExpired_CheckedChanged" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```

Comment: I can see that you are using the AutoPostBack in this components so that means that whenever you change something in this controls it will be posted to the server that will process the change and update the  ajax panel area with the results readed from server. So i dont think client side will be an good option in this case.

Comment: @Diego after having the values cleared I have to use the current value of currently active control to populate my gridview thats why using Postback or if there is any other option ??

Comment: Just noted now that you are using the UpdateMode="Conditional" so just the controls with Triggers will cause the update. The only thing is that your trigger controls are the one you need use so the good way to do what you whant is to process at server side.

Comment: Can you explain to me what are you trying to do ? like why do you need to clear the other fields when one changes ? If I understand correctly you just whant to search using one of the options, so why not clear the other contents on server side ?

Comment: @DiegoGarcia *so why not clear the other contents on server side ?*
 Like what contents can we clear..?

Comment: @DiegoGarcia okay Diego removed AutoPostBack..Now..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashwini Your code with the following code worked fine for me..
because it was that all the three should clear other two and **checkbox** was not working the way I needed with above code..so had to go other way round.. Anyways following code worked fine for me..
Now it clears **both** of the not selected ( among the three controls)

Thank-you once again..!

```
     <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkCss").blur(function () {
            $(".checkCssChk input").attr("checked", false);
            $(".checkCss").not(this).val("");
        });
        $(".checkCssChk input").change(function () {
            $(".checkCss").not(this).val("");
        })
    });
</script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" runat="server" CssClass="checkCss" onchange="tValue(this)"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDaysToExpire" runat="server" Width="80px" CssClass="checkCss" onchange="t2Value(this)"> ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkExpired" runat="server" Text="Show Expired" CssClass="checkCssChk" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tValue(txt) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtDaysToExpire.ClientID %>').value = "";
            document.getElementById('<%= chkExpired.ClientID %>').checked = false;
        }
        function t2Value(txt) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtExpiryDate.ClientID %>').value = "";
            document.getElementById('<%= chkExpired.ClientID %>').checked = false;
        }
     </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If not using the AutoPostBack:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDaysToExpire" runat="server" Width="80px" onchange="tValue(this)">   </asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Text="blah blah blah" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function tValue(txt)
  {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtTest.ClientID %>').value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>').checked = false;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: This goes for txtTest and CheckBox1only and for only one condition txtDaystoExpire_Textchanged , but about the condition if some   other control among the three is changed then the rest two will be cleared..?

Comment: Yeah, your code is working nice, I checked it, but as said earlier for one condition only..

Comment: I have given just as a sample. you can do the same for other control too. using onchange()

Comment: Came back after a looong time, and to express my thnx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ashwini you can do the same thing for the others:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDaysToExpire" runat="server" Width="80px" onchange="DaysToExpireChanged(this)">   </asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" runat="server" Text="blah blah blah" onchange="ExpiryDateChanged(this)" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkExpired" runat="server" onchange="ExpiredChanged" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function DaysToExpireChanged(txt)
  {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtExpiryDate.ClientID %>').value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%= chkExpired.ClientID %>').checked = false;
  }

  function ExpiryDateChanged(txt)
  {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtDaysToExpire.ClientID %>').value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%= chkExpired.ClientID %>').checked = false;
  }

  function ExpiredChanged(txt)
  {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtDaysToExpire.ClientID %>').value = "";
    document.getElementById('<%= txtExpiryDate.ClientID %>').value = "";
  }
 </script>
```

Or you can improve the logic to do just one function that process every changes.